# EasyTouch about unity3d Error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using Unity3D to create a demo.
The demo is like this: Use the EasyTouch to control the movement of the gameobject named "Player" —— the plane.

After creating the EasyTouch, I create a C# script like this:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour {
    public float m_speed = 1;

    protected Transform m_transform;

    public MovePlayer m_movePlayer;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        m_transform = this.transform;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
    }

    void OnEnable(){
        Debug.Log ("OnEnable");
        EasyJoystick.On_JoystickMoveStart += HandleOn_JoystickMoveStart;
        EasyJoystick.On_JoystickMove += HandleOn_JoystickMove;
        EasyJoystick.On_JoystickMoveEnd += HandleOn_JoystickMoveEnd;
    }

    void HandleOn_JoystickMoveStart (MovingJoystick move)
    {

    }

    void HandleOn_JoystickMoveEnd (MovingJoystick move)
    {
    }

    void HandleOn_JoystickMove (MovingJoystick move)
    {
        Debug.Log ("HandleOn_JoystickMove");

        if (m_transform == null) {
                m_transform = this.transform;
        }

        if (move.joystickName != "moveJoystick") {
            Debug.Log ("return");
            return;
        }

        float currentPositionX = this.gameObject.GetComponent<Transform> ().position.x;
        float currentPositionZ = this.gameObject.GetComponent<Transform> ().position.z;

        float joyPositionX = move.joystickAxis.x;
        float joyPositionY = move.joystickAxis.y;
        Debug.Log ("joyPositionX = " + joyPositionX + " joyPositionY = " + joyPositionY);

        float moveh = joyPositionX / 10;
        float movev = joyPositionY / 10;

        this.m_transform.Translate (new Vector3 (-joyPositionX/10, 0, -joyPositionY/10));
    }
}
```

When I start the game, the code worked fine, and the plane will be control.

Then I create the button by GUI.

When the button was clicked, the code `Application.LoadLevel(0)` will be called.And the level will restart.

But after I called `Application.LoadLevel(0)` to restart the game.
The plane will can not be control by the EasyTouch, and the Error message will appear:

```
MissingReferenceException: The object of type 'Player' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it.
Your script should either check if it is null or you should not destroy the object.
```

I wonder at why the "Player" will be null. 
The "Player" should be init after called  `Application.LoadLevel(0)`, doesn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Preamble

I have never used this EasyTouch plugin (fortunately? :D). So I'll make an assumptions on what I see in your code. If I'm wrong — sorry :)

## Answer

Take a look on this code:

```
void OnEnable(){
    Debug.Log ("OnEnable");
    EasyJoystick.On_JoystickMoveStart += HandleOn_JoystickMoveStart;
    EasyJoystick.On_JoystickMove += HandleOn_JoystickMove;
    EasyJoystick.On_JoystickMoveEnd += HandleOn_JoystickMoveEnd;
}
```

It looks like `EasyJoystick` is a static class. And you are subscribing to static events here. Then after calling `Application.LoadLevel()` the instance of your `Player` class marked as destroyed. But subscriptions don't go anywhere and once `EasyJoystick` fires one of the events (`On_JoystickMoveStart`, `On_JoystickMove` or `On_JoystickMoveEnd`) corresponding methods (`HandleOn_JoystickMoveStart`, `HandleOn_JoystickMove` or `HandleOn_JoystickMoveEnd`) are being invoked. This is why you get the exception. And it is probably thrown by this line (am I wrong? :)):

```
float currentPositionX = this.gameObject.GetComponent<Transform> ().position.x;
```

In order to fix the problem you need to unsubscribe `Player` instance(s) from the events mentioned before invoking `Application.LoadLevel()`.

## Side note

This:

```
float currentPositionX = this.gameObject.GetComponent<Transform> ().position.x;
```

can be rewritten as:

```
float currentPositionX = transform.position.x;
```

Though `currentPositionX` and `currentPositionY` are not used at all :D

## Edit. How to unsubscribe

Something like this:

```
void OnDisable(){
    Debug.Log ("OnDisable");
    EasyJoystick.On_JoystickMoveStart –= HandleOn_JoystickMoveStart;
    EasyJoystick.On_JoystickMove –= HandleOn_JoystickMove;
    EasyJoystick.On_JoystickMoveEnd –= HandleOn_JoystickMoveEnd;
}
```

Comment: I tried the solution, but it did not work. I rewritten as:float currentPositionX = transform.position.x; . But it comes the same mistake. I thought mistake reason is that, the transform will also try to get the Player instance. I also have a question: after I called 'Application.LoadLevel(0)', the Player instance should have bean init. Why also have the mistake?

Comment: Well, obviously writing "float currentPositionX = transform.position.x" will not solve the problem. Did you do code to unsubscribe Player instance from events? If so, show me how you did it.

Comment: I thought the train of thought is absolute correct!
 But, could you teach me how to unsubscribe Player instance from events?
 In my opinion, I should get the reference of the Player Instance to change the position of the plane.
 But if I get the reference of the Player, the mistake will appear.
 Could you give me a simple example to show how to unsubscribe Player instance from events? Thanks.

Comment: It works! Thanks very much! I'm a beginner of Unity3D. You've helped me a lot!